# How to use both member function and friend function operator overloading in same class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

As per an assignment requirement,

I am trying to implement prefix ++ and postfix ++ operator overloading both as member function and friend function in same class.

```
class dist {
private:
    int kMeter;
    int meter;
public:
    // postfix
    dist operator++(int unused) {
        dist dd = *this; 
        (this -> meter)++;
        return dd;
    }

    // prefix
    dist operator++() {
        ++(this -> meter);
        return *this;
    }

    dist(int k = 0, int m = 0) {
        kMeter = k;
        meter = m;
    }

    void print();
    int getMeter() const { return meter; }
    int getKMeter() const { return kMeter; }

    friend dist operator++(dist& d, int unused); //postfix
    friend dist operator++(dist& d); // prefix
};

dist operator++(dist& d, int unused) { // postfix friend func
    dist dd = d; // copy the old value into dd
    d.meter++;
    return dd; // return the original value of d
}

dist operator++(dist& d) { // friend prefix ++
    ++d.meter;
    return d; // return the final value of d
}
```

But when I trying to use prefix ++ or postfix ++ overloading it shows ambiguous error.

```
dist d2(1, 900);
dist d3(3, 800);

/// these following lines showing ambiguous error
cout << d2++ << endl;
cout << ++d3 << endl;
```

Now,

How can I use both type of operator overloading for same operator in same class file without getting any error.

Comment: Why do you want to have 2 different functions that do the exact same thing? Maybe an XY problem.

Comment: @super It’s an assignment requirement for my younger brother. That’s why I got confused

Comment: It is possible for the prefix form of `operator++()` to be a member, and the postfix a non-member, or vice versa.    It is not possible for either form to be simultaneously a member and a non-member since that results in ambiguity  (e.g. two functions that are both equally good match for `++x` or for `x++`).   A `friend` declaration declares the non-member form (so a `friend` declaration of the prefix form cannot co-exist with a member of the prefix form).

Comment: I suspect that your brother's teacher was a bit unclear about the assignment. I would suggest that your brother ask his teacher for clarification, or talk to his classmates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most operators can be overloaded ***either*** as member ***or*** nonmember function. *Some* operators (`=` `[]` `()` `->`) can be overloaded only as members. But you cannot have any oeprator **both** as a member **and** nonmember, specifically because it is unclear how to pick either one of them.

What the assignment wants is probably:

- you overload prefix ++ as a member and the postfix ++ as a nonmember (in your case, also friend)
- create two separate programs: in one, those operators are overloaded as members, in another - as nonmembers